# What IC can I use as controlled inverter

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logic-gates, inverter

Pretty much I want to find an IC with the following structure:

Inputs: I, a0...a7
Outputs: b0...b7

Where b0=a0 xor I, b1=a1 xor I, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually buy a quad 2-input XOR gate IC, and use 2 of them to implement this.

Part No: 74HCT86

Only about $0.50 each on digikey.

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/nexperia-usa-inc/74HCT86D-Q100118/1727-8017-6-ND/9381310

Comment: Is there a IC where one input to each gate is connected to the same signal? So there is only 1 signal to control all of the outputs?